# Firebase iOS - Unable to launch app

Tags: ios, firebase

I'm using Firebase for iOS inside a pod of my own. My architecture is like this :

```
MyProjet 
|    MyCustomPod
|    |   Firebase
```

I'm importing Firebase with these lines in podspec:

```
 s.dependency "Firebase/Core"
 s.dependency "Firebase/Messaging"
```

When I want to compile my project, if have to set the frameworks *FirebaseAnalytics*, *FirebaseInstanceID*, *FirebaseMessaging* as `Other Linker Flags`, it compiles correctly, but on execution, I have the following message :

```
 dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_PBDescriptor
  Referenced from: /Path/To/MyApp.app/Frameworks/MyPod.framework/MyPod
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Path/To/MyApp.app/Frameworks/MyPod.framework/MyPod
```

Has anyone already encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It could be tricky to get Firebase to work inside of another pod because Firebase's libraries are currently static. _OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_PBDescriptor is defined in the GoogleInterchangeUtilities pod.